# Incrementing a column upon using a query with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to increment (or change the value of) a column `[Obsoleted]` upon querying the database. I would like the functionality to be something similar to the following...

```
SELECT TOP 5 [PartNumber]
            ,[Description]
            ,[UPCCode]
FROM [BOMs].[PartsPrices]
WHERE [LastUpdated] IS NULL AND [Obsoleted] = 0
SET [Obsoleted] = 1
```

Basically, I want to have my `[Obsoleted]` column get changed to 1 so that it will never be queried by this query again (hence the `WHERE . . . [Obsoleted] = 0`. I haven't known how to word my question, so that's why I came here for help. Thanks for any advice and/or solutions! If you need more information, I'm more than willing to edit my question.

Comment: Are you using code in a programing language?  The syntax above is not TSQL.  The answer might be different if you are using a programming language vs direct TSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your table

```
UPDATE [BOMs].[PartsPrices]
    SET [Obsoleted] = 1
WHERE [LastUpdated] IS NULL AND [Obsoleted] = 0
```

If you also want to alter `LastUpdated` to the time this update occurred, you can use the following query instead:

```
UPDATE [BOMs].[PartsPrices]
    SET [Obsoleted] = 1,
        [LastUpdated] = GETDATE()
WHERE [LastUpdated] IS NULL AND [Obsoleted] = 0
```